# Select a point on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to add a feature where the user can look at a plot of all time stamps from several patients of a certain variable, select a point and see which patient that point belongs to, as well as all other information about the patient at that time stamp. My data is reactive because the SQL Query that fetches it requires user input. I'm trying to use click in plotOutput and nearPoints in the server, and the clicker will show up when hovered over the plot, although if I try to click on a point, nothing will happen (the data display will remain null). Here is what I have:

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
shinyUI(navbarPage("Choose Page",
               tabPanel("Page 1",
              #sidebar
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                  *unrelated tab*
              )
          )
      ),
      tabPanel("Overall Metrics",
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   h3("Metrics Across All Patients"),
                   selectInput("selecty1",
                               label = "Choose a variable to display on the y-axis:",
                               choices = list('Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3', 'Var4')),
                   dateRangeInput("dates1", label= "Date Range:"),
                   submitButton("Create Graph"),
                 ),
                 mainPanel(
                   plotOutput('plot1', click = "plotClick"),
                   verbatimTextOutput("click_info")
                 )
               )
      )
)
)

#server.R

library(shiny)
require(RODBC)
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
library(reshape)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

chan2 <- odbcConnect('date_base', uid='username')
queryString2 <- reactive({sprintf("**SQL Query**",input$dates1[1],input$dates1[2])}) 
overallData <- reactive({sqlQuery(chan2, queryString2())})

output$heartplot1 <- renderPlot({

ggplot(overallData(), aes_string(x = "Time_Stamp", y = input$selecty1)) + geom_point(size=2) + geom_line(aes(colour = factor(PatientNum))) + theme_bw() + stat_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,size=1)
})

output$click_info <- renderPrint({
nearPoints(overallData(), input$plotClick, addDist = FALSE)
  })
})
```

All demos I find of nearPoints use typical data tables, how can I make this work with reactive data, or is that not the problem here?

Comment: I think `ggvis` is better suited for this then `ggplot2`

Comment: Can you make an example that is self contained and doesn't need your database connection?